# CodeIgniter home controller giving 404 error in IIS 10 server

Tags: codeigniter-4, iis-10, custom-error-pages, php-8.2

I am trying to add CodeIgniter 4.3.2 with IIS 10 server config. But only base app URL I can  browse. when I am browsing home controller getting 404 error. I have tried the multiple solutions w.r.t. URL rewrite, .htacess and web.config update. But nothing working.

[/index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFKnl.png) => without index.php also its working

[/home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdera.png)

I have tried with all below URL's but not working.

http://localhost/app/index.php/home

http://localhost/app/index.php/home/index

http://localhost/app/home

http://localhost/app/home/index

Please help on this.

I have tried the following link as well, but didn't work.

[stlake2011 Wrote:](https://forum.codeigniter.com/post-335028.html)

Comment: Did you check the .ENV file? You have to adjust the base url at least

Comment: Please post a detailed page about the 404 error, or you can also try use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I have updated  $routes->setAutoRoute(true); in Routes.php then it started working now. Thank you :)